# Is there any solution for the error that is occur during execution

Tags: android, gradle, build.gradle

[image]

Caused by: org.gradle.workers.internal.DefaultWorkerExecutor$WorkExecutionException: A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.res.ParseLibraryResourcesTask$ParseResourcesRunnable
this error is generated while running the project on mobile

Comment: Please kindly provide the complete error..

Comment: i post the picture of errors above

Comment: Seems you have some problems with your xml.. navigate to activity_main.xml, and check if you have an extra ''<"

Comment: ok let me check